# How to target the parent nodes of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was just told this:

```
function openCurtain(cover) {
    /* hide(cover);*/
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
  }
```

> When this function runs, it is just going to target the first curtain.
> querySelector will only get the first element the selector matches.
>
> How to target the parent nodes of an element. The curtain is two
> parents above each div with class="embed-youtube".

In the code, how do I fix that?

Which is causing the following issue:

The outline, when I click on the first video, it fades in how it is supposed to.

After the play button is clicked.

When I click on the other videos it doesn’t work.

https://jsfiddle.net/xLkngsyd/

https://jsitor.com/kDARJVjvu

```
.curtain::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  outline: 1px solid #333;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.curtain.slide::after {
  outline: 1px solid #0059dd;
  transition: outline 2s ease-in;
}
```

[image]

Here is the entire code if that helps.

As you can see in the code example here, only the outline in the first video fades in after clicking it.

```js
(function initCover() {

  /* function show(el) {
     el.classList.remove("hide");
   }*/

  /* function hide(el) {
     el.classList.add("hide");
   }*/

  function openCurtain(cover) {
    /* hide(cover);*/
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
    return curtain;
  }

  /*function showVideo(curtain) {
    const thewrap = curtain.parentElement.querySelector(".wrap");
    show(thewrap);
  }*/

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget.parentElement;
    const curtain = openCurtain(cover);
    /* showVideo(curtain);*/
  }

  const covers = document.querySelectorAll(".embed-youtube-play");
  covers.forEach(function addHandler(cover) {
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
  });

}());



(function () {
  let YouTubeContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".embed-youtube");

  // Iterate over every YouTube container you may have
  for (let i = 0; i < YouTubeContainers.length; i++) {
    let container = YouTubeContainers[i];
    let imageSource = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + container.dataset.videoId + "/sddefault.jpg";

    // Load the Thumbnail Image asynchronously
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = imageSource;
    image.addEventListener("load", function () {
      container.appendChild(image);
    });

    // When the user clicks on the container, load the embedded YouTube video
    container.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
      let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

      iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
      iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "");
      iframe.setAttribute("allow", "accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture");
      // Important: add the autoplay GET parameter, otherwise the user would need to click over the YouTube video again to play it 
      iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + container.dataset.videoId + "?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&fs=0");

      // Clear Thumbnail and load the YouTube iframe
      container.innerHTML = "";
      container.appendChild(iframe);
    });
  }
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: white;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain {
  margin:auto auto 20px;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
}
.curtain::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}
.curtain::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  outline: 1px solid #333;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.curtain.slide::after {
  outline: 1px solid #0059dd;
  transition: outline 2s ease-in;

}
.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.embed-youtube {
  background-color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.embed-youtube.five {
  margin-bottom: 0;

}

.embed-youtube img {
  width: 100%;
  top: -16.84%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

/*.embed-youtube img,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play {
  cursor: default;
}*/

.embed-youtube img,
.embed-youtube iframe,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play:before {
  position: absolute;
}

.embed-youtube {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

 .slide img  {
  animation: fadeOutBack 3s forwards 0s;

}

@keyframes fadeOutBack {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  
    99.9% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    /*pointer-events: none;*/
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}


.embed-youtube iframe {

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
 animation: fade 3s ease-in 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}


.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 9px solid blue;
  background: transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #000000b3);

  z-index: 1;

}

.embed-youtube-play::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 27px solid blue;
  transform: translateX(4px);
}

.embed-youtube-play:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.embed-youtube-play:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="curtain">
        <div class="ratio-keeper">

            <!-- 1. Video Wrapper Container -->
            <div class="embed-youtube " data-video-id="djV11Xbc914">
                <!-- 2. The preview button that will contain the Play icon -->
                <button class="embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="curtain">
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <!-- 1. Video Wrapper Container -->
            <div class="embed-youtube " data-video-id="djV11Xbc914">
                <!-- 2. The preview button that will contain the Play icon -->
                <button class="embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="curtain">
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <!-- 1. Video Wrapper Container -->
            <div class="embed-youtube " data-video-id="djV11Xbc914">
                <!-- 2. The preview button that will contain the Play icon -->
                <button class="embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, if you only want the fade effect to play when you click the play button, make sure to adjust `const covers = ".embed-youtube"` to `".embed-youtube-play"` in coverClickHandler, then get the parent element in the click event (`evt.currentTarget.parentElement;`)

Comment: I am stuck: https://jsfiddle.net/rgzukvtc/

Comment: You can just move the `parentElement` to when you declare the cover variable: https://jsfiddle.net/p563n2h9/

Comment: It's still not working though. The outline still only fades in after the first video button is clicked. None of the other outlines fade in on the other players.

Answer (score 0):

`const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");`

This selector only selects the first element in the DOM with that class.

Comment: What needs to be adjusted in the code so that it works?

Comment: @EricaLevine Write the function correctly. You can use `this` or `eventTarget`.